# Creating a ring chart with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm attempting to create a "ring chart" similar to the ones found [here](https://www.scribbletone.com/typefaces/ff-chartwell) (scroll down to ring charts) with Highcharts using a donut chart. So, if I want to display a data value of 46% of something, it circles around counter-clockwise to 46% and stops.

I don't have a lot to go off of at this point, but [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjezY/) with what I have so far.

And code:

```
$(function () {

       // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    shadow: false,
                    center: ['50%', '50%']
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
            series: [ {
                name: 'Art Education',
                data: [
                        ['Covered by contributions',46]
                ],
                size: '70%',
                innerSize: '40%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        // display only if larger than 1
                        return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.series.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                    }
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Versions',
                data: [1, 2],
                size: '80%',
                innerSize: '70%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        // display only if larger than 1
                        return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="./js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="./js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 250px; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

2017 Update:

Highcharts can now do [Semi circle donut charts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle) which is what I was looking for. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/0w8egL6e/)

Comment: "it circles around counter-clockwise to 46%" - 46% of what?  46% of 360 degrees?

Comment: Yes, 46% of the 360 degree circle, preferably in a counter-clockwise fashion.

Comment: How about using polar chart instead of pie? In general, pie chart requires to have full circle, you can try to avoid that by setting some white color for slice, disabling dataLabel for such point etc, but this will be dirty solution, IMHO. The problem in polar will be with animation - since animate will start from center of a chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example using polar chart with some data interpolation: http://jsfiddle.net/ghvKY/

```
function interpolateData (min, max, step, index) {
    var d = [];

    // add points from start to one before last
    for(var i = min; i < max; i += step){
         d.push([i,index]);   
    }
    //add end point
    d.push([max, index]);

    return d;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work great for what I need it to do. Thanks!